# How to add only unique values to a ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to do the following in my application:

I am getting some `String` values from an some `Textviews`. I am adding this values to  `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` in the following way,where

`cart_list` is of the type `HashMap<String,String>>`  and cart is of the type `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`

```
    cart_list.put("quantity",""+qty);
    cart_list.put("item_id"+item_id_number,""+item_id_number);
    cart_list.put("Category",Itemname);
    cart_list.put("Details",Item_details);
    cart_list.put("Price",Item_price);
    cart_list.put("Currency",Item_currency);
    cart_list.put("images",images);
    cart.add(cart_list);
```

I want to add only unique values to `cart`. How can I check whether a given value is already present in the `ArrayList>. Please tell me step by step what to do.

Comment: You should choose some field to be unique, because if you want all to be unique, you would need to loop through every `ArrayList` item and check each item's HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
for(int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++){
     if(cart.get(i).containsKey(yourkey))
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The key already present in HashMap.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     if(cart.get(i).containsValue(yourvalue)){
           String key = getKeyByValue(cart.get(i), yourvalue);
           if(key.equals(yourkey)){
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The keys are same having same value.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
     }

}
```

and getKeyByValue method

```
public static <T, E> T getKeyByValue(Map<T, E> map, E value) {
    for (Entry<T, E> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In this **yourkey** which you want to check given key(String like quantity) is already present

**yourvalue** like Itemname in your **cart** `HashMap` value

Comment: I am using the same key, I just want to check whether the values associated with each key is different.

Comment: there is no inbuilt method named containsvalue

Comment: @Ann edited it's `cart.get(i).containsValue(yourvalue)`

Comment: It worked....I replaced the `return entry.getkey()` with `return entry.getvalue()` in the `getkeybyvalue` method. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the `Set` implementation instead of ArrayList

```
A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set.html) the documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set<String> st = cart_list.keySet();
    if(!st.contains("newKey")){
        cart_list.put("YourKey", "Yourvalue");
        cart.add(cart_list);    
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Dupliation not allowed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this for distinct sets**

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> DistN(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> col)
    {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> DistN;
        DistN = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++) {

                final HashMap<String, String> chval = new HashMap<String, String>();
                chval.put(NO, col.get(i).get(NO));
                chval.put(IE, col.get(i).get(IE));

                if (!DistN.contains(chval)) {

                    DistN.add(chval);
                }

        }

        return DistDN;

    }
```